# Inconsistent ASP.NET Web Api Pre-flight OPTIONS

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-options-method, preflight

I'm getting an inconsistent preflight HTTP Options request from my single page app. ***This only happens randomly sometimes*** and the only way I ameliorate the issue is by pressing F5 and things are good for a while until I kind of go "idle" for a little bit.

When it happens my Chrome Network Tab looks like this:

[image]

When my

- https://webui.myapp.com (AngularJS 1.1.5)
- https://api.myapp.com (ASP.NET Web Api .NET v4.5 on IIS 7)

My infrastructure breakdown

- AngularJS Application
- ASP.NET Web Api
- Visual Studio 2012
- IIS 7.5
- Windows 7

I've read a few articles and my web.config's system.webServer looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000"/>
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```